# How to split .avi file into scenes based on recording date/time?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-editing, avi

I have several huge .avi files which I have recorded years ago with a TRV510EPAL recorder on Hi8 tapes. A 90 minute tape takes about 19GB.

Now I need to split those files into individual scenes according to the recording date/time. Start a new scene when there is a big cap between date/time of two consecutive frames.
It would be nice if the tool could name the scenes according the date/time of the first frame of the scene.

How can I do this splitting automatically with e.g. ffmpeg or some other tool?

I'm total beginner with ffmpeg so a clear example is appreciated.

I prefer linux solution but windows is also fine.

Thank you for your support!

Comment: Can you post a couple of screenshots? Especially before and after near a date change.

Comment: Are the timestamps stored in a machine-readable way, or are they just hardcoded on top of the video itself?

Comment: grawity: How can I check this?

Comment: Where do you see the recording date? Is it visible in the frames, i.e. when you open the file in a video player, or is that something you see in the file's metadata? Screenshots would help.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I tried win10 movies&TV, win10 windows media player, vlc on win10, redhat movie player, ubuntu vlc but none of those show any recording time when playing the movie. The one that I remember can show it was windows movie maker on vista. I try to get one up and running and get some screenshots. vlc also has so many advanced settings that it could work also with vlc with correct settings.